# Can I read an indexeddb database from C#, or is any .net library written for this?

Tags: c#, .net, indexeddb

My web application reads and writes data to indexeddb, but at the end of the day, I want to read the data from indexeddb using a Windows Service, which is essentially a C# application. Then from the Windows Service, I want to read the data and want to send the data to a webserver some where.

Browser will not help in that case, because we are taking a scenario where user drops some data and shuts down the browser.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why does it need to be indexeddb, in particular?

Comment: Isn't the entire point of indexeddb to be hosted in the browser? If you need to access that database outside of the browser, you're probably using the wrong library then...

Comment: @glenebob: It is designed like this previously, we do not want to rewrite the whole package and the application.

Answer (score 1):

The standard packaging for .NET libraries is NuGet. If you [search nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=indexeddb), you'll see there are a number of packages for indexeddb. I'm not familiar with Indexeddb specifically, but this should give you a good starting point.